# Concentration / convergence of a gaussian random multivariate polynomial: computing mean and variance

Tags: probability, statistics, random-matrices, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails

Let $m,d \to \infty$ with $m/d \to \rho \in (0,\infty)$. Let $z_1,\ldots,z_m$ be iid from $N(0,I_d)$ and let $A$ and $B$ be $d \times d$  be deterministic psd matrices. Define the random variable $S \ge 0$ by
$$
S := \sum_{i,j}(z_i^\top A z_j)(z_i^\top B z_j)
= \sum_{i,j} trace(Az_jz_i^\top Bz_jz_i^\top)=\sum_{i,j}trace(B D_{j,\ell}),
$$
where $D_{j,\ell} := (w_j^\top w_\ell) w_jw_\ell^\top$,  with  $w_i := A^{1/2} z_i \sim N(0,A)$.

> **Question 1.** For appropriately normalized $A$ and $B$ (e.g to ensure that $trace(A) = \mathcal O(1)$, etc.), is it possible to concentrate $s$ only using $\rho$ and information about the eigenvalues of $A$, $B$, and $AB$?

**N.B.** By "concentrate", I mean write $S=s_0 + o_{\mathbb P}(1)$ for some  constant $s_0 \in [0,\infty)$.

For example, if $A = (1/d) I_d$, and $\lim_{d \to \infty }trace(B) = t \in [0,\infty)$,
one can show that (see this post https://mathoverflow.net/a/396431/78539)
$$
S \to s_0 = \rho(1+\rho)t,
\tag{1}
$$
in $L_2$ and thus in probability.

Thus, a satisfactory answer to the above question should recover this result at the least.

### Notes

- The method used to establish (1) doesn't seem to extend to case where neither $A$ nor $B$ is  proportional identity matrix. I'm hoping for a general strategy for attacking the above problem, and similar ones.
- We can write $S = f(z_1,\ldots,z_m)$, for a smooth (in fact, polynomial) function in the $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_m)$ random vector of size $md$ with components drawn iid from $N(0,1)$. If one could compute the mean and variance of $s$ (that is, limits thereof, in the limit $m,d \to \infty$ with $m/d \to \rho$), then one could use standard concentration inequalities for polynomials in Gaussians (e.g Hanson-Wright). This leads to the following question

> **Question 2.** What is the mean and variance of $S$ ?

Note that since I'm only interested in concentrating $s$ in the asymptotic limit ($m,d\to \infty$ with $m/d \to \rho$), it is sufficient to only compute the dorminant terms of the mean and variance of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer.** This would be a rather long comment or edit to the question, so I decided to post it here to start a discussion on a route. The (insufficient) contribution here is to compute the asympotic mean of $S$, thus partially answering **Question 1**. I hope to come back here with ideas to compute the variance of $S$.

---

**Change notation to** $\Lambda := B$ and $\Gamma : = A$.

**Assumption.** Suppose the following limits exist and are finite:

- $\lim_{d \to \infty}\mbox{tr}(\Gamma) = s$,
- $\lim_{d \to \infty} d \cdot \mbox{tr}(\Lambda \Gamma)=t$,
- $\lim_{d \to \infty}d^2\cdot \mbox{tr}(\Lambda \Gamma^2) = \overline{t}$.

> **Claim.** *In the limit $m,d \to \infty$ such that $m/d \to \rho \in (0,\infty)$, we have the following analytic limit for the expected value of $S$*
> $$
> \langle S\rangle \to \rho st + \rho^2 \overline{t}.
> $$

For example, if $\Gamma = (1/d)I_d$, then $s=1$ and $t=\overline{t}=\lim_{d \to \infty}\mbox{tr}(\Lambda)$, giving $\langle S\rangle \to \rho(\rho + 1)t$.

### Some experiments

[image]
[image]

***Proof of the claim.*** Since $S:=\sum_{j,\ell}\mbox{tr}(\Lambda D_{j,\ell})$, where $D_{j,\ell} := w_j w_j^\top w_\ell w_\ell^\top = (w_j^\top w_\ell)w_jw_\ell^\top \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$,
the expectation of $S$ is given by (thanks to linearity of expectation and trace operators)

$$
\langle S\rangle  = \sum_{j,\ell} \mbox{tr}(\Lambda \langle D_{j,\ell}\rangle).
$$

To compute the mean matrix $\langle D_{j,\ell}\rangle \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$, we distinguish between two cases.

- *Case 1: Diagonal terms ($j=\ell$).* We may write
  $D_{j,j} = \mbox{tr}(\Gamma)w_j w_j^\top + (\|w_\ell\|^2-\mbox{tr}(\Gamma))w_jw_j^\top$ which is dominated by the first term because $\|w_j\|^2$ has exponential concentration around its mean value $\mbox{tr}(\Gamma)$. Thus,

$$
\langle D_{j,j}\rangle = \mbox{tr}(\Gamma)\langle w_jw_j^\top \rangle + E = \mbox{tr}(\Gamma)(\Gamma+E),
$$

where $E$ is a $d \times d$ matrix with $\|E\|_{op} = o_{\mathbb P}(1)$ in the limit $d \to \infty$.

- *Case 2: Off-diagonal terms ($j \ne \ell$).* For any $a,b \in [d]$, we compute the $(a,b)$th entry of $\langle D_{j,\ell}\rangle $ as follows

$$
\begin{split}
\langle (D_{j,\ell})_{a,b}\rangle &= \langle (w_j^\top w_\ell) (w_jw_\ell^\top)_{a,b} \rangle = \langle (w_j^\top w_\ell) w_{a,j}w_{b,\ell}\rangle = \sum_c \langle w_{a,j}w_{c,j}w_{c,\ell}w_{b,\ell}\rangle\\
&= \sum_{c}\langle w_{a,j}w_{c,j}\rangle\langle w_{c,\ell}w_{b,\ell}\rangle = \sum_{c}\gamma_{a,c}\gamma_{c,b} =: (\Gamma^2)_{a,b}.
% \langle w_{a,j}^2w_{a,\ell} w_{b,\ell} \rangle + \langle w_{a,j}w_{b,j}w_{b,\ell}^2\rangle + \sum_{c \ne a,b}\langle w_{a,j}w_{c,j}w_{c,\ell}w_{b,\ell}\rangle
\end{split}
$$

Invoking (1) then yields

$$
\begin{split}
\langle S\rangle &= \sum_{j,l} \mbox{tr}(\Lambda\langle D_{j,\ell}\rangle)
= \mbox{tr}(\Gamma)\sum_j\mbox{tr}(\Lambda(\Gamma + E)) + \sum_{j \ne \ell} \mbox{tr}(\Lambda\Gamma^2)\\
&=\frac{m}{d}\mbox{tr}(\Gamma)(d\cdot \mbox{tr}(\Lambda(\Gamma + E)))+\frac{m(m-1)}{d^2}(d^2\cdot \mbox{tr}(\Lambda\Gamma^2)) \to \rho st + \rho^2 \overline{t}.
\end{split}
$$

This completes the proof of the claim. $\quad\quad\quad\Box$